# Explain why this procedure of easy RSA is insecure?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In class, we said that RSA uses as its modulus a product of 2 primes. let's look at a variation that uses a single prime number as the modulus. In other words, Bob would pick a 1024-bit prime number p and a public exponent e satisfying 2<=e

Comment: In class, we say that RSA uses as its modulus a product of 2 primes. Let's look at a variation that uses a single prime number as the modulus. In other words, Bob would pick a 1024_bit prime number p and a public exponent e satisfying 2<=e<p-1 = 1, calculate his private exponent d as the inverse of e modulo p-1, publish (e,p) as his public key and keep d secret. Then Alice could encrypt via the equation E(x) = mod(x^e , p) and Bob could decrypt via D(y) = mod(y^d , p).
.

Comment: Explain why this variation is insecure. In particular,  describe a procedure that Eve could use to recover the message x from the encrypted value y that she observes and the parameters (e,p) that are known to her. Analyze the running time of this procedure and make sure to justify why Eve could feasibly carry out this procedure without requiring computation resources.
please help me with this question

Comment: This is the complete question.

Answer (score 1):

After establishing that p was prime, Eve would know that Euler's totient function φ(*p*) = *p* - 1. She can then calculate the decryption key *d* as the multiplicative inverse of *e* modulo φ(*p*). Since the key *d* was supposed to be secret, this variation is insecure.